# What is the chance a random set of length L will be repeat itself in a random set of length M, where each number has X possible values?

Tags: combinatorics

The numbers within each set has X possible values (so X=100 means numbers run from 0..99).

Say I have a set of random numbers of length M (say M=1000).

What are the chances a random set of length L (say L=10) will repeat itself within the M set?